# C++: Operator matches across classes

Tags: c++, operators

I'm trying to do the following operation:

```
  R3MeshHalfEdge *tmp_edge = half_edge;
  R3Vector *tmp_vector = new R3Vector(R3zero_vector);

  do
  {
    **tmp_vector += tmp_edge->face->plane.Normal();**
    tmp_edge = tmp_edge->opposite->next;
  }while(tmp_edge != half_edge);
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
R3Mesh.cpp: In member function ‘void R3MeshVertex::UpdateNormal()’:
R3Mesh.cpp:1291: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘tmp_vector += tmp_edge->R3MeshHalfEdge::face->R3MeshFace::plane.R3Plane::Normal()’
```

HalfEdge has the following structure:

```
class R3MeshHalfEdge {
  public:
    // Constructors
    R3MeshHalfEdge(R3MeshVertex* vertex, R3MeshFace* face);

    R3MeshVertex *vertex;
    R3MeshFace *face;
    R3MeshHalfEdge *opposite;
    R3MeshHalfEdge *next;
    int id;
};
```

Face has the following structure:

```
class R3MeshFace {
  public:
    // Constructors
    R3MeshFace(void);
    R3MeshFace(const R3MeshFace& face);
    R3MeshFace(const vector <R3MeshVertex *>& vertices);

    // Property functions
    double Area(void) const;

    // Data
    vector<R3MeshVertex *> vertices;
    R3Plane plane;
    R3MeshHalfEdge *half_edge;
    int id;
};
```

Vector has the following public operation defined in the class:

```
class R3Vector {
 public:
  R3Vector& operator+=(const R3Vector& vector);
}
```

It is implemented as such:

```
R3Vector& R3Vector::
operator+=(const R3Vector& vector)
{
  // Add vector to this 
  v[0] += vector.v[0];
  v[1] += vector.v[1];
  v[2] += vector.v[2];
  return *this;
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler is giving the error.

Edit:
I forgot to include the Normal() definition for R3Plane:

```
class R3Plane{
  public:
    const R3Vector& Normal(void) const;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you added two asterisks before and after the offending line.

```
  R3Vector *tmp_vector = new R3Vector(R3zero_vector);

  do
  {
    **tmp_vector += tmp_edge->face->plane.Normal();**
```

Supposing you added two, and not one, at the beginning of the line, you had

```
    tmp_vector += tmp_edge->face->plane.Normal();
```

and `tmp_vector` is a pointer so you want

```
    *tmp_vector += tmp_edge->face->plane.Normal();
```

Comment: I'm so sorry - the two asterisks were supposed to bold the text. There are no asterisks on that line in the actual code.

Comment: code works as desired with the *tmp_vector += tmp_edge->face->plane.Normal(). Thanks!